# How can I handle a maze in a play-by-post game?

Tags: play-by-post, puzzle

So, I'm going to be running a classic Mutants and Masterminds adventure next week, "[Toys will be Toys](http://www.freeronin.com/2e_files/toyswbtoys.zip)". The crux of the game is the players racing their way through a series of rooms connected by passageways. Since this is a superhero game, there will be people moving at super-speed and teleporting. For the most part, I don't see an issue because most rooms include some situation that needs to be overcome, and there are some built-in brakes in some rooms that specifically target super-speed or teleporting. However, one room is specifically a maze and I find myself wondering how exactly one handles navigation of the branches without slowing things down to a crawl by asking them over and over again.

What's a good way to handle this? Have players provide navigation rules and present them with what they learn? Just give them a skill check to determine how long it takes them to bypass the maze? Slightly complicating things, the scenario has the walls shift if someone uses super-speed or teleportation within the maze (although it's not immediately apparent unless they're tracking a map and realize the maze doesn't make sense for a 2-dimensional unchanging layout).

[This post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/how-do-i-run-a-maze-scenario-without-using-a-map) has some interesting ideas for skipping a map entirely, but I'm specifically trying to figure out how to go about doing this in play-by-post where people typically say something like "I walk down the corridor" and it becomes very significant if they run into something 100 feet down a 200 foot corridor, but the other players have their own narratives potentially going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of [Mipui](https://www.mipui.net/app), an online map editor where editing is collaborative and the maps are persistent, so I think it can be a great match for your scenario.

Create a map and share it to all your players, have each player have a token, and then anyone can move their token whenever they like and you can draw the map in response to their movement.

My app is 100% free, but if you don't like it then any editor which is collaborative and persistent can also work, for example Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me whether you would consider skipping the map or not, but if yes then here's my take.

The Apocalypse Engine allows "custom moves" that can strip a scene to its core (usually stakes and players' decisions) and I think it would be a great fit for your concern.

Jason Cordova designed a really good maze move for Dungeon World, there is a discussion about it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/DungeonWorld/comments/4zwbl7/variant_of_jason_cordovas_custom_labyrinth_move/), I think it could fit your game with some adaptation to the M&M system.